# What is the default value of the usage property of the Source object?

Tags: stripe-payments

In "THE SOURCE OBJECT" in the right column of https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/object, "usage": "reusable".
Is "reusable" the default value (when you do not specify the usage property)?

As a basic view of the API, is the default value of each object the value in THE hoge OBJECT in the right column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value typically depends on the type of source you're creating. A `Source<Card>` for instance will be `single`; whereas, another source type may be `reusable`.

Comment: "A Source <Card> for instance will be single". Where is it written in the documentation?